# Manipulation of Input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyone who can help me how can for this logic using jQuery?

I have two checkboxes in my form. Once I click the first checkbox, the second checkbox will also check and vice versa. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first checkbox has an ID of checkbox1 and the second is checkbox2, do this:

```
$('#checkbox1').bind('click', function() {
  $("#checkbox2").prop("checked", true);
});
$('#checkbox2').bind('click', function() {
  $("#checkbox1").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: You should monitor `change` event instead of `click`. Checkbox state can be modified via spacebar or code also.

Comment: @mrtsherman: Actually, `click` is also triggered by a spacebar press. `mouseXXX` are explicitly mouse-only events.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this works for n checkboxes. Assign a class that links the checkboxes. When one changes state find the rest and set them to be the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/bumqH/

```
<input class="pair" type="checkbox" />
<input class="pair" type="checkbox" />

$('.pair').change( function() {
    $('.pair').not($(this)).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (un)check both checkboxes to the state of the clicked one: http://jsfiddle.net/DVMPm/. This piece of code works for any amount, not necessarily two.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```